# request license in form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, request

I make this code to show in live if the users license is already in DB, the code works in half.. only show the error if is alredy in DB but when the license isn't not show me nothing.. can you see where is my error and if this code is safe from sql injection?

code:

```
<?php
    sleep(1);
    include('connection.php');
    if($_REQUEST)
    {
        try {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT license FROM users_lic WHERE license = ?');
            $stmt->bindParam(1, $_REQUEST['license']); 
            $stmt->execute();
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                if($row['license'] > 0) // not available
                {
                    echo '<div id="Error">The license is already in our system</div>';
                }
                else 
                {
                    echo '<div id="Success">The license does not exist in our system</div>';
                }
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
```

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#lic').blur(function(){
        $('#Info_lic').html('<img src="img/loaders/loader.gif" alt="loader" />').fadeOut(1000);
        var license = $(this).val();        
        var dataString = 'license='+license;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/val_lic.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#Info_lic').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
                //alert(data);
            }
        });
    });              
});
```

the part of license form:

```
<div class="span4">
    <label><b>License : </b></label><input type="text" class="input-block-level" id="lic" name="license" />
    <div id="Info_lic"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sidenote: *"and if this code is safe from sql injection"* This would belong in SO's code review section. Plus, check your syntax in your PHP. SO's syntax highlighting shows something is incorrect.

Comment: You need to escape your `'` in (doesn't) `echo '<div id="Success">The license doesn't exit in our system</div>';` Do `echo '<div id="Success">The license doesn\'t exit in our system</div>';` or `echo "<div id='Success'>The license doesn't exit in our system</div>";` --- That alone will produce an error. Fix it and see if it works.

Comment: @Fred ii ok I fix that, thank you for your support but always show me only the error div, when the license is not in the DB not show me nothing...

Comment: You're welcome. Can you try `$stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['license']);` instead of `$stmt->bindParam(1, $_REQUEST['license']);`

Comment: the same result.. when the license exist in DB the code shows me the error div with "the license is alre......" but when I try with other number or just change one digit of the license I tried before not shows me the success div... I believe the issue is here = `else { echo '<div id="Success">The license does not exist in our system</div>' ; }` but I can't figure where

Comment: Can you try the query without the JS?

Comment: If it works without JS, then you know the problem is with JS and not PHP/SQL.

Comment: yes, it works without th js because the license is a unique index, but I need it live to evade to reload server

Comment: I think I know why it's not showing up. I will post an answer shortly. But this is in regards to PHP/SQL and not JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your row checking outside of your `while` loop and I have changed `if($row['license'] > 0)` to `if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)`

Give this a try now. (Tested on my server)

```
<?php
    sleep(1);
    include('connection.php');
    if($_REQUEST)
    {
        try {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT license FROM users_lic WHERE license = ?');
            $stmt->bindParam(1, $_REQUEST['license']); 
            $stmt->execute();
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)

    {
        echo '<div id="Error">The license is already in our system</div>';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<div id="Success">The license does not exist in our system</div>';
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: wow my friend that works very nice!! thank you for your support.

Comment: can with this show or hide the send button? or I need to create another js?

Comment: I think you may need to create another JS for that and I'm not very good with JS. I usually just find a code that works when I need to Google. @user3236149 I'm sure you will find something.